# Присвоить QPixmap другому QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt

Хочу присвоить значение одного `QPixmap` через функцию другому `QPixmap`-у, но выдается ошибка. Почему, и как нужно это сделать?
Пример кода:

```
class Class
{
public:
  void Function(QPixmap pix) { pixmap(pix); }

protected:
  QPixmap pixmap;
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка? Каким образом инициализируются `QPixmap`-ы? Выложите минимальный пример, позволяющий воспроизвести ошибку.

Comment: Class{
public:
    void Function(QPixmap pix){
        pixmap(pix);
    }
protected:
    QPixmap pixmap;

Answer (score 2):

Исправьте ваш код таким образом:

```
void Function(QPixmap pix) { pixmap = pix; }
```

Ещё дополню.

Ваш код не оптимален: вы передаёте аргумент в функцию **по значению**, т.е. функция получает копию объекта, вызывается конструктор копирования - потенциально дорогостоящая операция, совершенно избыточная в контексте вашей функции.

Передавайте в функцию константную ссылку на объект:

```
void Function(const QPixmap& pix)
```

или, если используете с++11, используйте семантику перемещения (если это допустимо в контексте вызова функции):

```
void Function(QPixmap&& pix)
```